# Split characters from txt file

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
def get_word_frequencies(filename):
    freqs = {}
    for line in open(filename):
        for char in line.split():
            if char in freqs:
                freqs[char] += 1
            else:
                freqs[char] = 1
  return freqs
```

I am facing a problem with split characters from text file and find their frequencies. I have write this code but it founds only the words.I want the letters in a A-Z dictionary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) and [`string.ascii_letters`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#string.ascii_letters) to get your letter count. The use of `string.ascii_letters` will allow you to only count letters, and not punctuation, etc.

```
from collections import Counter
from string import ascii_letters

def get_word_frequencies(filename):
    with open(filename) as f:
        c = Counter(f.read())
    return {k:v for k,v in c.items() if k in ascii_letters}

c = get_word_frequencies('derp.py')

print(c)
# {'o': 12, 'h': 1, 'C': 2, 't': 16, 'i': 18, 'y': 1, 'u': 5, 'f': 11, 'p': 6, 
# 'v': 2, 'c': 10, 'm': 7, 'n': 13, 'k': 3, 'd': 5, 'a': 6, 'q': 2, 'w': 3, 
# 's': 10, 'g': 3, 'r': 19, 'l': 6, 'e': 25}
```

Comment: Sorry..but what is derp.py?I have tried this but the only output is: t .I don't know what i did wrong...

Comment: Another problem is that the get_word_frequencies get me an name error and told that is not defined.

Comment: when i pass my file name it gets me a t!!

Comment: raceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#11>", line 1, in <module>
    getWordFrequencies('derp.py')
NameError: name 'getWordFrequencies' is not defined  that's the error...

Comment: No.,that not the problem..I have change it everywhere..same problem

Comment: When I try to do the same with my file I had an error about c that it's not defined...

Comment: Well I don't know what else to tell you :/ the code is fine and works for me and others.

Comment: it works!!!thanks..can I ask something else?If i would like to return me a dictionary with all the alphabet in a column and the frequencies at a second column?something like that a : 0.123 b: 0.456..

Answer (score 2):

If you want to iterate through letters individually, no need for `split`. Strings are directly iterable.

```
for char in line:
```

...Although, this will also count whitespace such as " ". If you want only letters, you might iterate through the words, and then iterate through each character in the word.

```
for word in line.split():
    for char in word:
```

---

Incidentally, Python already has a `Counter` class, so you don't necessarily need to construct a frequency dict manually.

```
>>> import collections
>>> print collections.Counter("hello how are you doing today?")
Counter({' ': 5, 'o': 5, 'a': 2, 'e': 2, 'd': 2, 'h': 2, 'l': 2, 'y': 2, 'g': 1, 'i': 1, 'n': 1, 'r': 1, 'u': 1, 't': 1, 'w': 1, '?': 1})
```